# Need a tip with UIBezierPath. Triangle Shape like Instagram Sign Up View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm trying to create a bezier path like the instagram triangle in the picture below, however I must be doing something wrong. The Bezier path does not show!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

[self drawTriangle];

}

- (IBAction)closeButton:(UIButton *)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)drawTriangle{

UIBezierPath* trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[trianglePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.signUpButton.center.x, self.signUpButton.frame.origin.y + 30)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.signUpButton.center.x - 10, self.imageView.frame.size.height)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.signUpButton.center.x + 10, self.imageView.frame.size.height)];

UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[fillColor setFill];
UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[strokeColor setStroke];

 [trianglePath fill];
[trianglePath stroke];

[trianglePath closePath];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Xcode 10 • Swift 4.2**

```
func drawTriangle(size: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, up:Bool) {

    let triangleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
    trianglePath.move(to: .zero)
    trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -size, y: up ? size : -size))
    trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size, y: up ? size : -size))
    trianglePath.close()
    triangleLayer.path = trianglePath.cgPath
    triangleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    triangleLayer.anchorPoint = .zero
    triangleLayer.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    triangleLayer.name = "triangle"
    view.layer.addSublayer(triangleLayer)
}

drawTriangle(size: 12, x: view.frame.midX/2, y: view.frame.midY, up: true)
drawTriangle(size: 12, x: view.frame.midX, y: view.frame.midY, up: false)
```

Comment: what is the "12" for? just clarifying- im trying to translate to objc

Comment: 12 is the size of the triangle

Comment: this didnt work for me for some reason. I think the size thing has the triangle flipped. Either way, I see no triangle

Comment: also you cant set the position directly like that, you have to set it as a CGPoint

Comment: Do you want a sample project ?

Comment: @SleepsOnNewspapers I have added the option to choose the position and the direction (up/down) of the arrow

Comment: Hey @Leo Dabus a sample project would be an extremely nice and generous gesture !

Comment: @SleepsOnNewspapers please send the url of a sample project in swift

Comment: @Nik's there is not sample project. as compromise, the above code is working beautifully

Comment: @LeoDabus can you please show us how to you add a direction and position?

Comment: @LeoDabus Good work. How can we draw like a popover design

Answer (score 3):

Here is some sample code that I have drawn a triangle for `UIButton` in my project and working great.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 80, 53);
[self.view addSubview:btn];

UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(40, 43)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(25, 53)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(55, 53)];
[bezierPath closePath];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.frame = btn.bounds;
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

[btn.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

and if you want to remove triangle of previous button when you click on next button then use following code snippet:

```
NSArray *arr = btn.layer.sublayers;

for (id class in arr) {

    if ([class isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]] ) {
        [class removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error with trying to remove the CAShapeLayer. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <CALayerArray: 0x17044afe0> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Comment: @SleepsOnNewspapers, Your exception message is clearly saying that you are removing the CALayer not CAShapeLayer. Check once again your code.

Comment: this code works, however:
 if ([arr[0] isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]] ) {
        [arr[0] removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
    else if ([arr[1] isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]] ) {
        [arr[1] removeFromSuperlayer];

Comment: @SleepsOnNewspapers Take a look at my answer, you will notice that I have named the layer triangle to allow you to identify your layer if you need to removeFromSuperlayer

Comment: @LeoDabus very insightful! I will mark u as the correct solution!