# How to create a view like UIPopover using UIBezierPaths in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uibezierpath

I have an app in which there are so many popover and every popover so many objects like `UIButtons`, `UILable`,`UITableView`.

Now I want to create view like popover using `UIBezierpaths`with upside arrow.

[image]

How can I do that in a `UIView`?

**don't want to any third party tool.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825252/need-a-tip-with-uibezierpath-triangle-shape-like-instagram-sign-up-view/30863372#30863372) here and just change the point values according to your need or path.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i have button in xib what can i do

Comment: & how to change y  position of arrow

Answer (score 0):

I am late but could be helpful to someone

```
func drawPopoverRadius(text: String) -> UIView {

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: .zero)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 51, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 51, y: 48))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 51/2 - 4, y: 48))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 51/2, y: 52))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 51/2 + 4, y: 48))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 48))
    path.close()
    layer.path = path.cgPath
layer.fillColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    layer.anchorPoint = .zero
    layer.name = "popover"
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 51, height: 52))
    label.clipsToBounds = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = NunitoSans.regular.font(size: 14)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.text = text
    label.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    return label
}
```