# Add a text above the triangle CAShapeLayer

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I use this function to draw an triangle

```
   func drawTriangle(size: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, up:Bool) {

       let triangleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
       let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
       trianglePath.move(to: .zero)
       trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -size, y: up ? size : -size))
       trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size, y: up ? size : -size))
       trianglePath.close()
       triangleLayer.path = trianglePath.cgPath
       triangleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
       triangleLayer.anchorPoint = .zero
       triangleLayer.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
       triangleLayer.name = "triangle"
       layer.addSublayer(triangleLayer)
   }
```

and call it:

```
   drawTriangle(size: 10, x: frame.minX + 45, y: 40, up: false)
```

How I can modify this function to add a text/ label above or under this triangle by using same x and y coordinate.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This looks familiar https://stackoverflow.com/a/30825352/2303865

Comment: Yes, I didn't say I write this function, I say I use this function.... and I need to add a text to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a label below the triangle you just need to create it at zero origin with zero size, choose the font size, set the text alignment to center and call sizeToFit. Then all you need to do is set the center of the label at the same point you have passed to the drawTriangle method but adding half of the label's height to the y value. To add it above the triangle you would need to subtract. half of the label's height and the size of the triangle.

```
let x = view.frame.minX + 45
let y: CGFloat = 40
drawTriangle(size: 10, x: x, y: y, up: false)
let label = UILabel(frame: .init(origin: .zero, size: .zero))
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 10)
label.textColor = .white
label.text = "StackOverFlow"
label.backgroundColor = .red
label.textAlignment = .center
label.sizeToFit()
let labelHalfHeight = label.frame.height/2
label.center = .init(x: x, y: y + labelHalfHeight)
view.backgroundColor = .blue
view.addSubview(label)
```